# When to use the word ell in a sentence such as " the Cape with ell and barn"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Question is whether the word ell should be capitalized in the sentence describing property such as

> The red Cape with ell and barn is at the end of the street.

Comment: I can't answer because I have no idea what the sentence means. I can't tell  what "Cape" might mean in this context; and the only meaning I know for "ell" is an archaic linear measure, in the phrase "Give him an inch and he'll take an ell".

Comment: There isn't enough context to answer the question. Please supply a few surrounding sentences and preferably the source.

Answer (score 2):

Lower case for ell and barn. They are not proper nouns.

[This article](https://www.bostonglobe.com/lifestyle/real-estate/2016/03/18/brand-new-house-from-this-old-house/CZLb5boyuag66K2xZe5JbK/story.html) from the Boston Globe gives some context. 'Cape' is a style of house and is capitalised along with 'Greek Revivals, Georgians, and Federal-style homes'. An ell is 'an extension usually at right angles to one end of a building' ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ell)) and is lower-cased along with 'barn'. (The article says 'a side ell with front porch houses the kitchen' and 'The master bedroom suite is above the kitchen ell'.)

Please provide more context with your question. Is this a sentence you read somewhere, or is it a sentence you want to write for some purpose? If you are writing for a general reader, it may be clearer for everyone if you specify: 'The red, L-shaped (or ell-shaped) Cape-style house with a barn is at the end of the street'. Even so, is the fact that it is L-shaped really that important?